# Why is this code bad?Unassigned local variable error with foreach

Tags: c#

This code is working.

```
public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){
    int a = 1;
    int[] i = new int[]{1,2,3};
    foreach(int n in i)
    {
        a = n;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

This code is good too.

```
public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){
    int a ;
    int[] i = new int[]{1,2,3};
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Although, next code is not working.
Compiler says "Use of unassigned local variable `a'".

```
public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){
    int a ;
    int[] i = new int[]{1,2,3};
    foreach(int n in i)
    {
        a = n;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Why is this code bad?

Comment: You are incorrect.  Your second version is also going to throw the same compiler error.

Comment: The compiler won´t evaluate *if* the loop might get executed. It simply uses the easieast assumption that it is possible that your loop won´t execute at all.

Comment: [Please check](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wWZcAM)

Comment: Type `int` is a structural type and as any other `struct`s must be fully initialized before it can be used. If compiler thinks that there is no guarantee that this type *is* initialized, it throws.

Answer (score 1):

Because compiler doesn't know if there are any elements in ***i*** variable. If there aren't any then ***a*** will stay unassigned.

Comment: If `a` was initially assigned as `int a = 0`,  `int? a = null`, or `int a = default(int)` then you'd be fine, but who knows what to write to the console if the value isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

The array `i` could be empty (from the compiler perspective), although we now from the declaration that `i` contains some elements. But I assume that the compiler "thinks" that the foreach-loop might be not executed and therefore there is the possibility that `a` will not be assigned by all code paths.

By the way - the second example has got the same problem:

```
public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){
        int a ;   // <= not assigened either
        int[] i = new int[]{1,2,3};
        System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler has no way of knowing whether `i` contains any element at all. If `i` is an empty array then `a` will be unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't smart enough to know that the line `a = n;` is guaranteed to run at least once. *You* know that that line will run, because it's inside of a foreach-loop which loops over a non-empty collection. But the compiler doesn't know this.

Since the compiler doesn't know that the line `a = n;` will run, it thinks that the variable `a` may be unassigned at the time that you do `System.Console.WriteLine(a)`. So it gives you an error message.